# Algebraic elements spans a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question:

Let $F$ be an extension field over $K$.

Let $u\in F$. Show that $u$ is algebraic over $K$ $\iff$ the subspace spanned by $\{1,u,u^2,\ldots, u^n\}$ is a field.

I have problems with the $\Leftarrow$ part.

Comment: Question is incomplete... what subspace are you referring to when you say  "subspace spanned by $\{1,u,u^2,…,u^n\}$  then $u$ is algebraic over $K$."

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397733/algebraic-field-extension-question. My answer there answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

$u$ has an inverse: then obtain a relation.